# q- When to return like "defer.resolve(myData); return defer.promise;" VS simply "return myData" in promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, q, deferred, resolve

I've been trying to write better code on my node.js server and after reading some blog posts like the following:

- http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/ (angular specific but same concept)
- http://bahmutov.calepin.co/linking-promises.html

I am still not sure if I'm returning my data down the promise chain the "right way".

I cannot tell when it's appropriate to return or pass data down a promise like this

**case 1**

```
var promise = function () {
    var defer = q.defer();
    var myData = "hi"
    defer.resolve(myData);
    return d.promise;
};
```

or like this.

**case 2**

```
   var promise = function () {
        var myData = "hi"
        return myData;
    };
```

I'm assuming is that if **I know** something will be returned where it's not possible for the promise chain to break then use **case 2** but if their is a change it could fail (i.e. it's returning data from a network call but the user is offline) then use **case 1** so it can handle both cases. Is that correct or do I have a misunderstanding about how this flow/process works.

Comment: Show us how you call/use that `promise` function. The difference should be obvious then.

Comment: Actually the proper way to immediately create a promise for a value is `return Q("hi");`

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you are returning a result which is instantly known or computed, while you are wrapping it in a promise in the first case. Whether or not you want to do this depends on whether it should be transparent for the caller of your function if the result is computed asynchronously or not. If you return a promise you are free to change the implementation of your function later to compute or retrieve the result asynchronously.

Two hints:

1. You are not using a promise in case 2 so don't call your function `promise`.
2. In the first case you can just `return q("hi");` to wrap the literal in a promise.

Answer (score 0):

1. promise is for those who engage callback hell, which means your jobs are Asynchronous and chained
2. for a simple case like $.ajax().success(callback1).fail(callback2) is type of promise
   3.your case is not Asynchronous, it might be like this:

```js
var promise1 = function() {
  //async get file name
}

var promise2 = function(filename) {
  var defer = q.defer();
  var myData = "hi"

  //async
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        defer.reject(err);
      } else {
        defer.resolve(myData);
      }
    }
  }
  return d.promise;
};
var promise3 = function(data) {
  //use data do something
}

var onError(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

var onDone(result) {
  console.log(result)
}

//your logic might look like
promise1.then(promise2).then(promise3).catch(onError).done(onDone);
```